# Change date format in Numbers 3.2

Tags: numbers

I recently updated Numbers to 3.2.

I want to be able to put a date in a cell numerically (8-22-14) and then have it show up with the month name, day, and year (August 22, 2014) without having to do a formula. I do not need the time.

Answer (score 4):

- Click the Format button in the upper right
- Select the "Cell" tab
- Under Data Format select "Date & Time"
- Under Date select your prefered format.

You should be able to enter a date in these newly formatted cells any format (like 8-22-14) and it should change to your selected format.

[image]
[image]

Comment: This doesn't actually work for me. I paste a date in from a properly-formatted cell, and it says "automatic" in the format. When I set it to date & time, it just changes it back to automatic when I leave and reenter the cell.