# Change date format for column of existing non-US format datetimes in Numbers

Tags: numbers

I can't believe I have to ask this, but here I am.

I have a Numbers (Numbers version 6.0 (6194)) sheet with data from an imported CSV file.  One column is date/time info, formatted like so:

```
21.05.2018 12:00
```

This is the correct date format in the country I am in.  My Mac knows this, so I assume Numbers ought to.

I need to get rid of the time from this col.  You'd think that would be pretty simple.  I select the cells in that col (not including the header, in case that single plain text cell confuses things), then click `Format`, then `Cell`, then under `Data Format` I choose `Date & Time`.  No matter what `Date` or `Time` option I choose ... absolutely nothing happens.  My selected column of dates does not change - the displayed text is in exactly the same format as it started as, as shown above.

I know there isn't, but it is as if there is an "Apply" button I am missing, so my chosen settings aren't actually applied.  If I click another cell in the sheet, then back to one of the ones I just tried to format, the `Data Format` has gone back to `Automatic`, not whatever I just chose.

Searching for help turns up [the official Apple guide](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH17075) which, AFAICT, tells me to do exactly what I am doing.

I also found [this old question and answer right here on Stackexchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/142877/change-date-format-in-numbers-3-2) which seems again to be exactly what I am doing - though the answer suggests that typing in *new* dates will result in them being formatted as required.  Maybe I can't reformat *existing* dates in the sheet?  That makes no sense!

What am I missing?

#### Edit

I tried adding a new col and using a formula to generate a date without the time:

```
YEAR($A2)−MONTH($A2)−DAY($A2)
```

But it just shows an error:

> The function “YEAR” expects a date, but cell A2 contains a string.

Comment: I don't have time to writeup a full solution, but if you switch it to 05/21/2018 12:00 you'll see that it starts working. It's not expecting dots and it's not expecting the day first.

Comment: @EzekielElin Thanks - so I need to manually change the format in order to be able to automatically change the format?  That ... seems crazy?  In any case, I have about ~1K rows, that isn't going to work.

Comment: @EzekielElin BTW I am not in the US; the date format I am starting from is correct. My Mac region settings are set correctly, so both macOS and therefore I assume Numbers know the local date format (which is what I have).

Comment: There is one correct worldwide date format, 2019-04-28 (that is, yyyy-MM-dd). It is universally understood. It sorts well. It does not have odd or technology-breaking symbols. The standard also includes accommodations for time zones and times. See: [ISO 8601 intro](https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1179/).

Comment: If, as seems possible, Numbers thinks the values are strings rather than dates, you could try doing a search and replace to change the '.' characters to '/' and see if that fixes it. You might need to do this in the CSV file (if you have access to it) before opening it in Numbers.

Comment: @JoelReid thanks, I'm aware of that. In fact, you can see I'm trying to convert the European date format I have into that format.  In any case, knowing about it doesn't help me here.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your date is simply not in a format Numbers natively recognizes. To test this failure-mode and see the same symptom, try typing in something else it may not recognize, like 999999999999, and set it to a date format. Again, it doesn't change, because Numbers doesn't want to assume how to parse it, and risk outputting incorrect values.

A solution is to pre-parse the input by field. Here's a demo using [`MID`](https://help.apple.com/functions/mac/8.1/#/ffa5bee222) to extract the year, month, and date fields by their position in the string, and hand them off to the `DATE` function.

```
=DATE(MID($A2,7,4),MID($A2,4,2),MID($A2,1,2))
```

[image: screenshot of the above formula in action]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The date format is correct for the country I am in, and macOS region settings are set for this country. I can't believe Numbers understands only US date formats!?

Comment: Bizarre. Yikes, Apple.

Comment: @Don'tPanic It could be a Numbers bug that it doesn't recognise all local date formats when reading CSV files. Or maybe the date column is quoted in the CSV and so Numbers interpreted it as strings?

Comment: @JamesRandom yes it is quoted in the source CSV, but then it has to be bcs it has the time there: "25.04.2019 12:00".  I suppose I could parse the CSV to get rid of it ... ugh.

Comment: I don't use Numbers much, but it doesn't seem to have options for specifying/overriding the types when you import CSV (unlike Excel, for example) which would be what you need here, I guess.

Comment: I just set my date format to German (the first one I found that used . in dates) and imported a CSV file using "25.04.2019" format. It all worked correctly and I was able to apply a different date format. I tried with some of the dates quoted and some not. That didn't make any difference. None had times though ... maybe I should try that

Comment: @JoelReid Thanks for the MID formula, short term I'm using that.  This feels so silly though!  I'll wait a while to see if any other answers or come in, if not I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Just tried with dates and times in the same format as yours (quoted and unquoted) and it all seemed to work as expected. So no idea what has happened with yours. (Same version of Numbers)

Comment: @JamesRandom Interesting! When you say you set your date format to German - you mean in Sys prefs -> language and region -> you choose Germany?

Comment: @Don'tPanic Exactly.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Just set my region back to UK and imported the CSV again. This time I can't apply a date format. They are fixed strings.

Comment: A note to any SE editors: We all know "comments are not for extended conversation", but please consider leaving comments intact as they hold details from the group effort to diagnose the bizarre behavior of Apple Numbers' date handling, the very crux of the original question. The manual string parsing shouldn't be necessary, and we're having problems with error reproducibility.

Answer (score 0):

Add a formula replacing $A2 with the cell you wish to use.

```
DATEVALUE(MID($A2,1,10)) + TIMEVALUE(MID(A2,12,5))
```